# Color of UIToolbar not changing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitoolbar, tint

I have created a UIToolbar. I am trying to give it black color using:

```
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

or

toolbar's `background` property. But its color does not change in either case.

How can I change it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried setting the tint property on UIToolbar? ie:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIToolbar *toolbar=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 46)];
  toolbar.tintColor=[UIColor redColor];
  [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
  [toolbar release];
}
```

[Detailed in the apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006927-CH3-SW1)

Comment: unfortunately it doeson't response to tintcolor either

Comment: tools = [[uitoolbar alloc]
         
         initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 46.01f)];

Comment: I just tried creating a new "view-based" application and added the (updated) code above to the viewController and it worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

IN iOS 7 you need to set the **barTintColor** Property-

```
UIToolbar *doneToolbar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 584, 320, 44)];
doneToolbar.translucent=NO;
doneToolbar.barTintColor=[UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:doneToolbar];
```

I have used it its working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Use this after you allocate and initialize you toolbar object:

```
toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

On IOS 10, apparently we also need to call `sizeToFit` on the `UIToolBar` to change the background color:

This worked for me:

```
let dummyToolbar = UIToolbar()
dummyToolbar.barTintColor = .lightGray
dummyToolbar.sizeToFit() // without this line it doesn't work
```