# How to change the bottom toolbar tint color without changing the navigator bar tint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitoolbar, tintcolor

I want to set the navigator bar tint to white  but the bottom tool bar tint to red.

The navigator bar tint is set at storyboard, and the tool bar tint is set in code.

`self.navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor=UIColor.redColor()`

But the code dose not work.

Answer (score 2):

Swift:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    var nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    nav?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    nav?.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.orangeColor()]
}
```

Objective-C:

```
 NSDictionary *textTitleOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor darkGrayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, nil];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textTitleOptions];

textTitleOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor darkGrayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Objectivec-c

```
UIToolbar *doneToolbar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 
     self.view.frame.size.height-44, 320, 44)];

    doneToolbar.translucent=NO;
    doneToolbar.barTintColor=[UIColor redColor];
  [self.view addSubview:doneTool  bar];
```

for more information click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581644/color-of-uitoolbar-not-changing)

Comment: I't is the answer. I used .tintColor but the .barTintColor.